# Odoo 10 How to get to propagate variables to load in all routes?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I'm working into a new theme so I've created some variables I need to load into a web template everywhere, so I've put them into a custom route. My trouble now is that they're shown only at my custom route (where my template is), and not a homepage URL, for instance.

Is there any way I could solve this?

Comment: remove greetings

Comment: Your custom route is different then the base one so it is not reflating. You can extend that route and add your custom variables.